# How can I get httparty to work with Glassfish? Getting 400 BadRequest response

Tags: rest, glassfish, httparty

Using: Glassfish v3.  Httparty 0.6.1 & 0.5.2.

I'm starting glassfish using "mvn glassfish:run" (maven-glassfish-plugin)  Everything works in the application.

This url works in RESTClient, cURL, and in the browser, but when I try with httpparty at the command line, I get this:

```
$> httparty -v "http://localhost:8080/parakeet/tickets/111"
GET http://localhost:8080/parakeet/tickets/111

400 BadRequest
content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
connection: close
date: Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:15:34 GMT
content-length: 0
```

I figure it's because of a header or something.  I've tried using httparty to send the following headers:

```
-H "Content-type":"application/json" -H "charset":"UTF-8" -H "Accept":"*/*"
```

And all combinations of the above, including

```
-H "Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to sniff the request (e.g. with wireshark) to find the differences.

Comment: Couldn't get Wireshark to pick up localhost traffic and it was Friday at 4 so didn't feel like pushing this out to somewhere else just to handle this.  Good though, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparrently Glassfish requires a "User-Agent" header.  It's working with anything, just as long as it is set.  This works (ripped from Chrome's resource panel):

```
httparty -v -H "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4" http://localhost:8080/parakeet/tickets/34
```

As does this

```
httparty -v -H "User-Agent":"Commander Cool" http://localhost:8080/parakeet/tickets/34
```